# Regressing (Very) Smooth Time Series

Tags: regression, time-series

What are the possible problems/issues of regressing smooth time series with almost no fluctuation?
Here is a specific example.

[image: My Example]

Is there anything I have to pay attention to when interpreting coefficients? Or is there no proper way to regress time series like these? If so, what are the reasons?

Answer (score 3):

One thing to consider, is that it looks like you *may* have a unit root, though not necessarily.

An example of a unit root would be the stochastic process $y_k=y_{k−1}+\epsilon_{k−1}$, where the error term is mean-zero.

Unit roots can cause problems. For one, they are not stationary processes. Using OLS relies on stationarity. A violation can lead to a 'spurious regression': invalid estimates but with a high R-squared.

However, these problems are solvable. The first step is to run a unit-root test, of which there are many.

I suggest looking elsewhere for further material on this, e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_root). There is lots out there and a full treatment would be outside the scope of one answer.

Comment: +1, although to me it looks like stationary series with break, since the article you linked to does not mention this possibility, but I don't think this warrants separate answer, I will just add that there are also breakpoint unit root tests such as Zivot-Andrews test that might be more appropriate here.

Comment: Great point, thanks!